# Qt: warning paintEngine should not be called on show()

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem where Qt displays a warning when I call show() on a dialog from outside the constructor.

This does not happen on my dsktop computer but on my ARM device where I have compiled Qt. I have a clash that shows a dialog as follows:

```
SplashVideo::SplashVideo(const QString & videoPath, QWidget * parent)
:QDialog(parent)
{
    this->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    m_mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface);
    m_videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(m_videoWidget);
    this->setLayout(layout);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);    
    m_mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(videoPath));
    m_mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(m_videoWidget);
    connect(m_mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),
        this, SLOT(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));
    m_mediaPlayer->play();
}
```

Now, I have the mediaStatusChanged handler where I call show as follows (other things get done but they are not important):

```
void SplashVideo::mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
    if (status == QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia) {
        this->show();
    }
}
```

The whole thing runs with a custom event loop as:

```
SplashVideo video(videoPath);
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(&video, SIGNAL(mediaPlayFinished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```

When I run this, I get the warning:

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
```

However, if I call show in the constructor, all is fine. Also, this only happens on my linux based ARM device. On a desktop linux system, it is fine.

Comment: Why there is more than one warning message? Is it possible `status == QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia` is called more than once? Maybe the first one doesn't rise the message? It may be a Qt bug, I cannot see any problem here. You may also try to use `setAttribute( Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true );` as a workaround (if it helps)

Comment: The bufferedMedia status gets called only once. I think the message is coming from multiple paint events. Also, this Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent has no affect either (does not even exist anymore in qt 5). I am on Qt 5.5.1